# Hide link button inside repeater based on role in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I used Web Site Administration Tool  for creating User ,Role etc.  I have Menu in Site Master.How can i hide a link button(Edit) inside the repeater control based on the role assigned.ie if an administrator login he can view the Edit link button,but for user it won't be visible.

If the link button or button is out side the repeater means i can hide and show using below code but i have no idea for link button inside repeater.Appreciate your help for this.

```
     If (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")) Then
        Button1.Visible = True
     Else
     End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at overriding the databinding event, check the role, find the control you want to change the visibility of.